# click after blur doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am editing textbox and click on the button directly and it doesn't fire click event of button.

There are many similar posts suggesting using `onmousedown` instead of `onclick` but I don't find it to be the solution. As I am doing some work on blur event of my text input and some validation on click on button. `onmousedown` will be called before blur means I can't do validation after blur. I just want to *Call click after blur*. Is there any way to do it?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onblur="txtblr()">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclk()" value="button">
```

**Javascript**

```
function txtblr(){
if(confirm('relly?')) {
    console.log('blur');
  }
 else {
    console.log('dont blur');
  }
}

function btnclk(){
    console.log('click');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wou5n1e8/)

Comment: include all relevatn code to OP

Comment: @guradio updated example code

Comment: If you look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp It seems to work correctly

Comment: call btnclk(); inside txtblr();

Comment: @arturmoroz why? I don't want validation to be fired every time I remove mouse from text box.

Comment: You have probably pressed "prevent this page from creating additional dialog" in your Chrome browser. Try restarting it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/GV3YY/1/

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to Call click after blur.

You are.

```js
function txtblr() {
  console.log('blur');
}

function btnclk() {
  console.log('click');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="txtblr()">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclk()" value="button">
```

### The problem: `alert()` blocks the UI

The button's `onclick` event is not being triggered when you have an `alert()` (or a `confirm()`) on your `onblur`. `alert()`s block your UI from making any other events on the page. Here's essentially what happens when the button is clicked when the textbox has focus:

- Textbox's `onblur` is fired which immediately fires an `alert()`.
- The `alert()` blocks the UI thread - you move the mouse to *click* the alert's OK button; or you don't. In any case, any further UI events (i.e. the button `onclick`) are rejected because of the `alert()`.

### The solution: Do not block the UI

Generally, it is a bad idea to block the brower from executing anything else. This creates a bad user experience. Following workarounds tell you how to avoid it.

#### `alert()` using `setTimeout()`

One workaround is to `alert()` using `setTimeout()`, ensuring that it doesn't block the page. However, this does not *wait* for the `alert()` to be acknowledged by the user to move to the button's `onclick` event.

```js
function txtblr() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    alert('blur');
  }, 100);
}

function btnclk() {
  console.log('click');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="txtblr()">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclk()" value="button">
```

#### Preferably, use other methods to get user feedback

Another, more preferable solution would be not rely on `alert()`s and `confirm()`s to get users' input, and implement a non-blocking modal - of which you would find a [ton of libraries](https://www.google.com/?q=js%20modal).

Comment: +1 but in my project it is not working. I have found that I am using confirm box in blur. Now I have updated my question with confirm box.

Comment: Javascript alerts and confirms block the browser from processing anything else, and you should avoid using them whenever possible. Check the updated answer for some workarounds.

Comment: I am using confirmation, not alert. Unless user passes confirmation, click should not be executed. with that, it won't work :(\

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I'm understanding your question. It sounds like what you want is to call the function used in your click handler (*i.e.*, `btnclk()`) when the `blur` event is registered on the `<input />` element (the `text`-type `<input />`, that is). If that's the case, try something like the below:

```
I'm not positive I'm understanding your question. It sounds like what you want is to call the function used in your click handler (*i.e.*, `btnclk()`) when the `blur` event is registered on the `<input />` element (the `text`-type `<input />`, that is). If that's the case, try something like the below:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document
    .querySelector('input[type="text"]')
    .addEventListener('blur', btnclk);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function txtblr(){
if(confirm('relly?')) {
    console.log('blur');
  }
 else {
    console.log('dont blur');
  }
}

function btnclk(){
    txtblr();
    console.log('click');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="txtblr()">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclk()" value="button">
```

I think this is your expectation.

Comment: These two events are completely independent. I don't have to call blur everytime I click.

Answer (score -1):

you can call your click function in the blur like below...so once the text box is blur your blur actions is done and also your click actions is done by calling the click function.

**Javascript**

```
function txtblr(){
 alert('blur');
 btnclk();
}

function btnclk(){
 alert('click');
}
```